# How To sync online database (of web application) and offline database (of Desktop Application)?

Tags: database, synchronization

I have 2 application

1st Desktop Application – Which has database on local pc

2nd Web Application – Which has database on server

If internet is unavailable then i m storing data on desktop application and when internet is available data should be store on the server and should also update the data which was stored when internet connection is unavailable

```
Can you please tell me how above can be achieved
```

Desktop Application is C# Win form
Web Application is Asp.ne / C# Web application

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you read up on merge replication?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your database technology is, but Microsoft makes the [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx) to solve problems like this.

Comment: i m using MSSQL Server 2008 r2 , but can it solve my issue that if local pc in not having internet then i m store data in local pc and then i want to update to server , but web app is currently using server db then there may be conflict of data and ids generated by identity column

Comment: Sync Framework allows you to implement conflict resolution strategies.  It's good to avoid identity columns if you know they are going to be replicated.